# Uploading image and pdf files with metadata to Sharepoint site

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint

I have a sharepoint site and i upload files to it through email.
The problem is even though all the files get uploaded only the metadata of Office files are getting auto filled.
Can anyone tell me how to get the other files also to auto fill the metadata?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That SharePoint autofills the metadata with Office files is a service from Microsoft. Any other filetypes you will need to implement your on `SPEmailEventReceiver` - in that you can do whatever you like with the files and get the files` metadata etc.